# Output to txt and cvs as one line

Tags: powershell

Good day,

I am looking to output result of a Get-NetTcpConnection into a txt and cvs files simultaneously.

This is how I do it now:

```
$netstat = Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object -Property CreationTime,LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State

$netstat | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\$env:COMPUTERNAME-$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HH.mm).csv -NoTypeInformation
$netstat | FT -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\$env:COMPUTERNAME-$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HH.mm).txt
```

Is there a way to do that as a one liner instead of using a variable?

Something like this:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object -Property CreationTime,LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\$env:COMPUTERNAME-$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HH.mm).csv -NoTypeInformation;
    $_ | FT -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\$env:COMPUTERNAME-$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HH.mm).txt
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"Tee-object" is build to pass the data/output straight through the pipeline from one end to other end with out format.

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object -Property CreationTime,LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State  |Tee-Object -FilePath "C:\Users\Narayana\Desktop\Testing Dir\temp2.txt" | Export-Excel -Path "C:\Users\Narayana\Desktop\Testing Dir\temp2.xlsx"
```

Comment: very interesting thank you. Does not quite work as I need it though because I want to have the properties of the Out-File or Export-Csv but can only have one

Comment: Instead of using Export-Excel, you can use Export-CSV

Comment: Also, I can suggest you to write a module and use Import- module in multiple servers..

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many attempts to get this done in a one liner like you have requested but, have been fruitless.

However, you can always just make your own function to perform this work and run it as a one liner?

```
function Get-NetStat{

    $netstat = Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object -Property CreationTime,LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State 

    if ($netstat)
    {
        $netstat | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\$env:COMPUTERNAME-$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HH.mm).csv -NoTypeInformation
        $netstat | FT -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\$env:COMPUTERNAME-$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd-HH.mm).txt
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $Error
    }

}
```

Comment: Sadly this will be ran on multiple servers so I am not sure a function is the best approach. Thank you nonetheless!

Comment: @Norskyi - Do you have a list of names or IPs that you will be running this on?

You could also create this against remote machines with the -CimSession parameter within Get-NetTCPConnection. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps